# Warning en PHP: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: php

He creado una función con PHP para extraer unos datos de una web; mientras hice pruebas individuales con ella (fingiendo ser "humano" mediante un User-agent) no hubo problema, pero al incorporarla a mi script y ejecutarlo, como hace 15 comprobaciones seguidas en diferentes subpáginas de esa web (en concreto intenta extraer la fecha de formación de un grupo musical, y en cada tanda intenta localizar el de 15 bandas diferentes), la web nota que en realidad soy un "bot" y rechaza la conexión (da el mensaje de error que figura como título del hilo).

Es mi primera aproximación al asunto y seguramente lo esté abordando de forma muy básica (programo en PHP "a lo bruto", simplemente estoy usando file_get_contents), ¿alguna recomendación de por dónde tirar para "engañar" a la web?

```
  function fecha_debut($url)
  {
    $encabezado = "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0";
    $desconexion = 5;

    $opciones = array("http" => array("header" => $encabezado, "timeout" => $desconexion));
    $contexto = stream_context_create($opciones);

    $html = file_get_contents($url, false, $contexto);

    $patron1 = "/(?<=formed )[0-9]{4}/";
    $patron2 = '/(?<=disco_year_y.{2}">)[0-9]{4}/';

    if(preg_match($patron1, $html, $coincidencia)) return $fecha = $coincidencia[0];
    elseif(preg_match_all($patron2, $html, $coincidencias)) return $fecha = min($coincidencias[0]);
  }
```

EDITO: He probado lo que propone el usuario cooper, añadir una función sleep (de 10 s), pero además de que sigue teniendo apuntada mi matrícula (ayer me funcionó cambiar el User-agent para esto), ocurre un nuevo error:

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

EDITO2: Solucionado el error del tiempo máximo de ejecución; gracias, Igmer Rodriguez. El problema es que la web me ha debido de incluir en una lista negra y ya no hay manera de conectar con ella.

EDITO3: En efecto: "We're sorry, but your IP address has been automatically blocked from this site because our firewall has detected there could be problematic activity from your IP address."

EDITO4: A través de un proxy puedo volver a acceder a la web con mi navegador, pero el script sigue fallando; ¿puede que ser porque sigue intentando acceder a través de mi verdadera ip? ¿Tendría que añadirle código al script para que vaya a través del proxy?

Comment: Hola, te invito a leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Para poder ayudarte necesitamos que seas más específico y proveas el código suficiente en donde se pueda ver el error, donde digas cuál es el comportamiento deseado y el resultado esperado. Saludos

Comment: La verdad es que no hay error, la función hace lo que se espera de ella, pero la web rechaza la conexión por las razones que he dicho.

Comment: Se me ocurre (como medida un poco chapuzas pero sencilla y por lo que comentas, probablemente efectiva), que pongas un sleep de X segundos para evitar ese problema.

Comment: He añadido el código de mi función; espero que sea suficiente.

Comment: El problema es la configuracion del servidor, tiene como maximo tiempo de ejecucion 30 seg para un script, puedes agregar ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);  al inicio de tu script